# How to make a scatter plot of one numerical variable and one categorical variable

Tags: r

I'm using the esoph dataset that is available by default in Rstudio.

I would like to make a scatter plot of the probability of contracting oesophageal cancer ('ncases' variable) with each of the different alcohol consumption groups ('alcgp' variable).

I tried:

```
plot(esoph$ncases ~ esoph$alcgp, xlab="Alcohol Consumption", ylab="Ncases", main="Alcgp Correlation with Ncases", col="lightblue")
```

But this gave me a boxplot since the parameter 'esoph$alcgp' given is not numerical variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(esoph$ncases, esoph$alcgp, xlab="Alcohol Consumption",yaxt = "n", 
     ylab="Ncases", main="Alcgp Correlation with Ncases", col="lightblue")
axis(2, at=1:4, labels=levels(esoph$alcgp))
```